# How to mount a NTFS read/write volume on Mac OS encrypted by Veracrypt?

Tags: macos, ntfs-3g, veracrypt

It's an external hard drive. My Mac has installed Fuse and NTFS-3G but it only mounts only read. I have been searching a lot in the web and I haven't find any solution. Please advise.
Info: Macbook late 2008 with El Capitan. Fuse v3.6.0. Veracrypt v1.19. Thank you.

Comment: You are saying that your NTFS volume is encrypted with Veracrypt?  If that is the case, you are going to want to decrypt it, mount it, then encrypt it.  You should clarify your question by editing it.

Comment: Hi Ramhound, thanks for replying. I have it encrypted but I would like it to continue like that, for security purposes. Do you have a recommendation for configuring Veracrypt to use NTFS-3G?